# Problem with empty cells in siunitx 2.6f

Tags: siunitx

I've just updated to TeX Live 2015, which updates `siunitx` to v2.6f. Now tables that include some empty cells do not compile anymore, with the error:

```
! Misplaced \cr.\reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr
```

See the MWE below. This works fine with `siunitx` 2.6e, but not the new version. When commenting the second row, it compiles fine with 2.6f as well.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}   

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{SS}
  0.232 & 0.043 \\
  0.051 &       \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply add an empty group in there `{}`

Comment: @Johannes_B, it works. But sounds like a downgrade instead upgrade! Maybe a bug in the package?

Comment: @Sigur We have the author here, he can judge it best ;-)

Comment: At me this MWE works! I have recent version of MikTeX and siunitx.

Comment: @Zarko. Well, it doesn't compile with TeX Liver 2015, but does with 2014. I assumed that was due to the update to siunitx 2.6f. Which version do you have?

Comment: The problem shows only in the last column. The `\sisetup` settings are irrelevant, it would be better to remove them in order to make the example really minimal. The suggested workaround of filling in `{}` is good, but a bug fix would be better, of course.

Comment: ups, I haven't recent version of `siunitx`. It is v2.6e from 2015/01/21.

Comment: Using the previous version of `siunitx` with TL 2015 works around the problem. So it does look like the upgrade to the package may be the source of the error. Has somebody pinged the author?

Comment: Remember: if you are reporting a specific bug in a package then TeX-sx is the _wrong_ place. Yes I'm active here but even then might miss things, and for other packages who knows.

Comment: On this specific issue: I know what the change is that causes it: I need to think about it a bit.

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, should I open a bug report on Git Hub?

Comment: @Jörg Would be best. I'll likely fix this later today.

Comment: I've logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/271 and will do a release later today (I need to merge another few things from my laptop into the Git repo).

Comment: I've uploaded a fix to CTAN. I'm minded to close this question as it's an out-and-out bug report and they are generally off-topic (unless they come down to asking for a work-around for a bug that seems unlikely to get fixed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug which has been fixed in the meantime.